# scheduling task with powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0, webclient, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule task on remote computer where i was successful in scheduling a task on remote computer its not executing. like i wanted to download a file on some triggered time.
in my task scheduler it shows task is completed successfully but i m not seeing any file downloaded.

```
 $ComputerName = "win12"
 $cr=Get-Credential $ComputerName\administrator    
 $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cr

 Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {       
     $start = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    [string]$Result = schtasks /create /tn "kk" /tr "powershell.exe (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://server12/vdir/OracleXE.exe','C:\abc.exe')" /sc once /st $start /ru "administrator" /rp "passw0rd@12" 
     $Result += schtasks /run /tn "kk"

    $Result

}
```

even triggered time is passed or i forced task to Run, the file is not downloaded. when i run command alone it download file fine but not with task scheduler.

Comment: Can you verify that the user context has access to the remote system. "administrator" sounds like a local account, not a domain account. Try running the command with runas.

Comment: what OS ? Is the script running as expected without the task scheduler ? can you try to run the task as "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE" ? Do you need a proxy to access server12 ?

Comment: @JonC yes, that is administrator of that remote machine... it has access to execute task. but task is in only ready status always...it dont executes or shows executed successfully but do not executed.

Comment: @Kayasax OS = windows server 2012 , and i dont need proxy to access server12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are how quotes are handled in powershell and by schtasks. Since the /tr command needs to be surrounded by double quotes, single quotes are used where double quotes are needed inside the command. These are in turn converted to double quotes. This is incompatible with powershell.exe since it in turn can't interpret double quotes inside the command.

The only workaround I have found so far is to convert the command to Base64, which preserves the exact formatting of the command, and pass it to powershell.exe using the -encodedCommand argument

```
$ComputerName = "win12"
$cr=Get-Credential $ComputerName\administrator    
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cr

$command = "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://server12/vdir/OracleXE.exe','C:\abc.exe')"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {       
    $start = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    [string]$Result = schtasks /create /tn "kk" /tr "powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand" /sc once /st $start /ru "administrator" /rp "passw0rd@12" 
    $Result += schtasks /run /tn "kk"

    $Result
}
```

**Update:**
Another approach which might be a bit less convoluted but requires PowerShell 3.0 is to use Scheduled Jobs.

```
$ComputerName = "win12"
$cr=Get-Credential $ComputerName\administrator    
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cr

$command = {(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(
    'http://server12/vdir/OracleXE.exe','C:\abc.exe')}

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
  Register-ScheduledJob -Name kk -ScriptBlock $command;
  (get-scheduledjob kk).Run() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you have problems with kerberos doublehop delegation. My suggestions:

1. create a ps1 file and schedule the script file
2. setup and use CredSSP for authentocation in Invoke-command
3. may be the scheduled job will be more suitable for this case than scheduled task.